# New installation 18.04 - startup broken

Tags: 18.04, startup, desktop-environments, .desktop

I successfully installed the LTS version.

I cannot login to my desktop, it just shows my desktop background but no sign of unity / gnome.

The only way I can use my desktop is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> which gets me to the shell where I can login and then run `startx`. Desktop now magically loads.

So everytime I start the computer I would need to do that. Is there a way to fix this? How can I debug this problem?

Comment: Try this first `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` which reset the login manager and prompt you to choose which one you want to use (choose gdm3). Honestly though, I had this problem once too and if it is a fresh install of Ubuntu, you may be better off just to wipe everything and install again because who knows what else is messed up. Start with that first command though.  ** Quick edit, if this is an upgrade to 18.04 and not an install, post back here before doing anything else as the instructions will be different.

Comment: Please confirm the ISO you downloaded to install with is not corrupted by using checksum: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0